# how to access function in factory outside controller

Tags: angularjs

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
  firstname:<input type="text" ng-model="data.firstName">
  lastname:<input type="text" ng-model="data.lastName">
  <br>name is : <strong>{{data.firstName}}&nbsp;{{data.lastName}}</strong>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
  name in 2nd controller: {{data.firstName}}&nbsp;{{data.lastName}}
  <button ng-click="updateData('kv','a')">click</button>
</div>
<button onclick = "ChangeEvn()"/>
    </div>
    <script>
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.factory('MyService', function(){
      return {
        data: {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: ''
        },
        update: function(first, last) {
          this.data.firstName = first;
          this.data.lastName = last;
        }
      };
    });

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, MyService){
  $scope.data = MyService.data;
});
myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, MyService){
   $scope.data = MyService.data;
   $scope.updateData = function(first, last) {
     MyService.update(first, last);
   }
});


function ChangeEvn() 
{
  alert("Ok");
  myApp.factory.update("Hello", ".....");//doesn't work
}
    </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

In the above code value is passed between two controllers using factory .Now i want to update first name and lastname using button click. button click function is outside the controller(i require that) . Now how to access the update outside controller myApp.factory.update("Hello", "....."); this statement doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) of services:

> To use an Angular service, you add it as a dependency for the component (controller, service, filter or directive) that depends on the service. Angular's dependency injection subsystem takes care of the rest.

You are trying to access the service method outside of an angular component. That is not at all recommended, if possible at all. If you are using angular, try to do everything "inside Angular subsystem". Trying to bypass the angular context will only cause problems, and it's not needed at all.

If you want to use a service method, then create a MainController, inject the service in it, attach the controller to some HTML element, and put your update button as a child of that element.

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <button onclick="updateData('FirstName', 'LastName')" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        myApp.factory('MyService', function () {
            return {
                data: {
                    firstName: '',
                    lastName: ''
                },
                update: function (first, last) {
                    this.data.firstName = first;
                    this.data.lastName = last;
                }
            };
        });

        myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
            $scope.updateData = MyService.update;
        });

    </script>
</body>
```